# Limit SSH key to SCP only

Tags: linux, ssh, automation

**Problem:**

I don't have root access to the server (i.e, I can't/don't want to change any system-wide server configuration), and I want to use scp with an alternative Identity File (e.g, `.ssh/id_rsa_for_scp`) to automate the download of some files from the server, but I don't want the same **key** to be used to access the server through ssh.

Answer (score 23):

After you copy your keyfile to the server:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_for_scp legendaryuser@192.168.1.1
```

(To simplify the example, we will assume the client's machine ~/.ssh/config is already configured. For more details about `~/.ssh/config` run `man ssh_config`)

```
Host testmachine
    Hostname 192.168.1.1
    User legendaryuser
    BatchMode yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_for_scp
```

You will need to edit the server's `/home/legendaryuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

From:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAAC3nZCXExxHUEBR...
```

To: (this version allows download and upload)

```
command="if [[ \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\" =~ ^scp.? ]]; then $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ; else echo Access Denied; fi" ssh-rsa AAAAAC3nZCXExxHUEBR...
```

If you want to limit scp to "download-only mode" and only to files from a specific directory, do:

```
command="if [[ \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\" =~ ^scp[[:space:]]-f[[:space:]]/full/path/to/dir/.? ]]; then $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ; else echo Access Denied; fi" ssh-rsa AAAAAC3nZCXExxHUEBR...
```

And last, lets add some more restrictions to the key, just to be safe:

```
command="if [[ \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\" =~ ^scp[[:space:]]-f[[:space:]]/full/path/to/dir/.? ]]; then $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ; else echo ERRO Access Denied; fi",no-pty,no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa AAAAAC3nZCXExxHUEBR...
```

You can see more details about the `authorized_keys` file by running:

```
man sshd
```

Ps: You can also add `from=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to the limit the use of the key from a specific IP address or network.

Pps: Sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Wow. Nice answer! :)

Comment: Or use the `scponly`, which does basically the same without writing too much regexes.

Comment: @Jakuje, Yes, I could... if I had root access to the server. This solution is intended to help a user that doesn't have the power to make any changes on the system from which he needs to copy the files.

Comment: @JesseAdelman, thank you, it's very kind of you. =)

Comment: You don't need a root access to set up `scponly` (if you download/install it in your home directory). It is nothing against your solution, but just for reference that there is already a tool to do that.

Comment: @Jakuje https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki/Install#Edit_etcshells Hmm. How are you going to do that without root access? For that matter, how are you going to install scponly package without root access? The question specifies that no root access is available. I think this answer meets the requirements along with the given descriptions.

Comment: @JesseAdelman 1) you can "install" any script into home directory. 2) You don't need to set it into the shells. Setting command to the key is enough.

Comment: @Jakuje OK, cool. Why not put that as an answer and demonstrate? I'd love to see how, too. :D

Comment: @Jakuje [`scponly`](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/) seems like a good solution, except it appears discontinued/abandoned?

Comment: @aexl seems like that. There could be some more up-to-date fork somewhere. I do not personally use that so I am not familiar with its development.

Comment: Awesome ! thank you very much

Comment: This is  simple and elegant solution that requires no new packages to install. Tools like rssh and scponly seem to be defunct

Comment: I had to replace _^scp[[:space:]]-f[[:space:]]_ with _^/usr/libexec/sftp-server_ for a macOS server

Answer (score 2):

Supplement to @Michael Richard's answer.

zsh will return an error:

```sh
zsh:1: no such file or directory: scp ...
```

This problem also exist in bash.

To solve it, replace

```sh
... then $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ; ...
```

to

```sh
... then $SHELL -c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ; ...
```