# Allow SCP/SSH to a chrooted environment only?

Tags: ssh, scp, chroot

Is there a way to do this without installing a package like `rssh` or `scponly`, as they seem woefully out of date and full of security problems?
Is there any newer tool I could use? `ssh` is an optional requirement, just being able to `scp` would be good also.

Can't use `sftp`, or else `openssh` configuration would do.

Comment: You can start a sshd daemon in a "chroot jail", as long as you don't use an already used port (TCP/22 as default). You need the binary, all related libraries  and some additional parametters to start the daemon on a different port.

Comment: https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_jailkit_pam_chroot.html

Comment: Maybe this helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes

Comment: @poige That sounds interesting, so I could use the pam module instead of using jailkit at all? And if not, at least jailkit is being updated still!

Comment: dunno, not using it

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/852309/limit-ssh-key-to-scp-only